# Rails Missing helper file application_helper.rb_helper.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

OS: Windows 10 x64
Rails: 4.2.5.1
Ruby: 2.2.4

Hello, I am running rails on windows and installed it with the Rails Installer. On a fresh generated application I get this error:

> Missing helper file helpers/c:/myapp/app/helpers/application_helper.rb_helper.rb

When I create the file named application_helper.rb_helper.rb. The error changes to:

> uninitialized constant C

I am creating my own thread for this because every other user who had this issue seems to in a folder called user; mine is not. I assume this is because I am on windows and do not have RVM.

Comment: It would probably help if you include the contents of the file(s) in question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To fix the issue, I renamed the project folder to all lower-case and moved the directory from c:\ to c:\workspace

Comment: This also worked for me. The `railsinstaller` program created `C:\Sites` .  To fix the problem I had to rename this to `C:\sites`. The problem occurs if the server is being run from a bash prompt where the path is `/c/sites` but not if the path is `/c/Sites`.

Comment: I had a totally different path but the same problem. Solution was, again, converting the path to lower-case only.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that since Ruby 2.2.x every filesystem is treated like its case-sensitive.
Coming from this https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10700

You can surely use any mix of upper-/lowercase in your path but you must pay 100% attention you stick to that since a single letter written differently behind a `cd` on a command line or within the working directory of a script will trigger the problem.

e.g. when your Rails app is in a folder named `RailsApp`:

`PS C:\>cd RailsApp
PS C:\RailsApp>rails c production`

works just fine.

While

`PS C:\>cd railsapp
PS C:\railsapp>rails c production`

will fail.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you used the Rails [`helper`](http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper) method somewhere in your code and that you provided the file's full name and not just the prefix. Something like this:

```
helper 'application_helper.rb'
```

What should just be written as:

```
helper 'application'
```